# A Foreign key referring Triple from Annotation has the wrong number of columns.

Tags: java, hibernate

Although I made a little research on this, and I found a lot of threats opened in Internet, I couldn't solve my problem. I attach my code:

**Triple.java**  the primary key is made by 3 URIs from three different concepts, but it is the same column (is it a problem?)

```
        @Entity
        @IdClass(ConceptPk.class)
        @Table(name = "triple")
        public class TripleDBModel {

            protected List<Annotation> annotations;
            public String conceptUriSubject;
            public String conceptUriObject;
            public String conceptUriPredicate;
            public String id;



            @ManyToMany(
                    cascade={CascadeType.ALL},  
                    fetch=FetchType.LAZY
            )   
            @JoinTable(name = "triple_has_annotation", 
                    joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="annotation_id"),
                    inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="uri_concept_subject", referencedColumnName="triple_id"), @JoinColumn(name="uri_concept_object", referencedColumnName="triple_id"), @JoinColumn(name="uri_concept_predicate", referencedColumnName="triple_id")
         })//EDIT
            public List<Annotation> getAnnotations() {
                return annotations;
            }
            public void setAnnotations(List<Annotation> annotations) {
                this.annotations = annotations;
            }
            @Id 
            @Column(name = "uri_concept_subject", length = 100)
            public String getConceptUriSubject() {
                return conceptUriSubject;
            }
            public void setConceptUriSubject(String conceptUriSubject) {
                this.conceptUriSubject = conceptUriSubject;
            }
            @Id 
            @Column(name = "uri_concept_object", length = 100)
            public String getConceptUriObject() {
                return conceptUriObject;
            }
            public void setConceptUriObject(String conceptUriObject) {
                this.conceptUriObject = conceptUriObject;
            }
            @Id 
            @Column(name = "uri_concept_predicate", length = 100)
            public String getConceptUriPredicate() {
                return conceptUriPredicate;
            }
            public void setConceptUriPredicate(String conceptUriPredicate) {
                this.conceptUriPredicate = conceptUriPredicate;
            }

 @Id
        @Column(name = "triple_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
    }
```

**ConceptPk.java**

```
    @Embeddable
    public class ConceptPk implements java.io.Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        public String conceptUriSubject;
        public String conceptUriObject;
        public String conceptUriPredicate;

        @Id
        @Column(name = "uri", length = 100, unique = true, nullable = false)
        public String getConceptUriSubject() {
            return conceptUriSubject;
        }
        public void setConceptUriSubject(String conceptUriSubject) {
            this.conceptUriSubject = conceptUriSubject;
        }

        @Id
        @Column(name = "uri", length = 100, unique = true, nullable = false)
        public String getConceptUriObject() {
            return conceptUriObject;
        }
        public void setConceptUriObject(String conceptUriObject) {
            this.conceptUriObject = conceptUriObject;
        }

        @Id
        @Column(name = "uri", length = 100, unique = true, nullable = false)
        public String getConceptUriPredicate() {
            return conceptUriPredicate;
        }
        public void setConceptUriPredicate(String conceptUriPredicate) {
            this.conceptUriPredicate = conceptUriPredicate;
        }
```

**Annotation.java**

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "annotations")
    public class Annotation {

        private Integer id;
        private List<TripleDBModel> triples;  

    @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "annotation_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
        public Integer getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

    @ManyToMany(
                cascade={CascadeType.ALL},
                mappedBy = "annotations", //EDIT
                fetch=FetchType.LAZY
        )   
        public List<TripleDBModel> getTriples() {
            return triples;
        }

        public void setTriples(List<TripleDBModel> triples) {
            this.triples = triples;
        }
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: A Foreign key refering TripleDBModel from Annotation has the wrong number of column. should be 3
```

What am I doing wrong?? Thanks in advance

Comment: Why did you set the column name for all 3 id columns in ConceptPK to "uri"? They should be different or otherwise they'd point to the same column.

Comment: Because the primary key is the combination of 3 concepts, so the 3 of them must point to the uri, the identifier of concept

Comment: You still have to reference 3 different columns in the dataset. You can't have multiple datasets define a foreign key for a 4th. The foreign key is defined in the `Tripple` table and I doubt it has a column `uri`, does it?

Comment: I eddited my question, the field `annotation_id` is not in Tripple, but in Annotation. The primary key of Tripple is the composed by 3 annotation_id, of 3 different annotations. `annotation_id` is the name in the database of te field `id`. Is this correct?

Comment: I added `triple_id` as a identifier of Triple, what was what you meant??

Comment: No, I meant ConceptPK is treated as the IdClass and thus its 3 fields should use 3 different columns which are the 3 pk columns in your Triple table.

Comment: But I need them to be the same field. Triple is made by 3 concepts, and one Triple can not be duplicated. Therefore I need 3 identifiers, one for each concept, and the identifier is the field `uri`. How could I model this?? Thanks

Comment: You have 3 foreign keys and add a composite unique key constraint on that (or a composite primary key, which is always unique)

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand really good... How am I going to reference the same field `uri` 3 times?? Do I need ConceptPK.java or is enough having just one reference in Triple.java? If so, how am I going to make any difference between the 3 concepts am I going to have? Thanks, and sorry

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453731/multiple-foreign-keys-in-one-table-to-1-other-table-in-mysql This question says that it is possible, as I understand. Maybe the error doesn't come from there (????)

Comment: Your Triple table is likely to have 3 columns containing the uri of each concept. Thus ConceptPK needs to map each field to the corresponding column. It doesn't matter in that case whether the pk of a concept is called uri, since you're working on a tripple which needs to distinguish between the 3 parts of its pk. Just imagine me telling you "The uri in tripple is wrong." Your answer would likely be "Which uri?" or "Which of the 3?". JPA has the same question. :)

Comment: The link you provided deals with plain SQL not with JPA. In fact, there you have 3 different foreign keys reference the same column in another table. What you want to provide for JPA in ConceptPK is the names of the 3 foreign key columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The final solution is:

**ConceptPk.java**

```
@Embeddable
public class ConceptPk implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public Concept conceptUriSubject;
    public Concept conceptUriObject;
    public Concept conceptUriPredicate;

    @Id 
    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name="uri_concept_subject")
    public Concept getConceptUriSubject() {
        return conceptUriSubject;
    }
    public void setConceptUriSubject(Concept conceptUriSubject) {
        this.conceptUriSubject = conceptUriSubject;
    }

    @Id 
    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name="uri_concept_object")
    public Concept getConceptUriObject() {
        return conceptUriObject;
    }
    public void setConceptUriObject(Concept conceptUriObject) {
        this.conceptUriObject = conceptUriObject;
    }

    @Id 
    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name="uri_concept_predicate")
    public Concept getConceptUriPredicate() {
        return conceptUriPredicate;
    }
    public void setConceptUriPredicate(Concept conceptUriPredicate) {
        this.conceptUriPredicate = conceptUriPredicate;
    }
```

**Triple.java**

```
@Entity
@IdClass(ConceptPk.class)
@Table(name = "triple")
public class TripleDBModel {

    protected List<Annotation> annotations;
    public Concept conceptUriSubject;
    public Concept conceptUriObject;
    public Concept conceptUriPredicate;



    @ManyToMany(
            cascade={CascadeType.ALL }, 
            fetch=FetchType.LAZY
    )   
    @JoinTable(name = "triple_has_annotation", 
            joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="uri_concept_subject"), @JoinColumn(name="uri_concept_object"), @JoinColumn(name="uri_concept_predicate") },          
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="annotation_id") )
    public List<Annotation> getAnnotations() {
        return annotations;
    }
    public void setAnnotations(List<Annotation> annotations) {
        this.annotations = annotations;
    }
    @Id 
    @Column(name = "uri_concept_subject", length = 100)
    public Concept getConceptUriSubject() {
        return conceptUriSubject;
    }
    public void setConceptUriSubject(Concept conceptUriSubject) {
        this.conceptUriSubject = conceptUriSubject;
    }
    @Id 
    @Column(name = "uri_concept_object", length = 100)
    public Concept getConceptUriObject() {
        return conceptUriObject;
    }
    public void setConceptUriObject(Concept conceptUriObject) {
        this.conceptUriObject = conceptUriObject;
    }
    @Id 
    @Column(name = "uri_concept_predicate", length = 100)
    public Concept getConceptUriPredicate() {
        return conceptUriPredicate;
    }
    public void setConceptUriPredicate(Concept conceptUriPredicate) {
        this.conceptUriPredicate = conceptUriPredicate;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is the cause of the error message you get, but your mapping has several errors:

1. Each of the `@JoinColumn` in your `inverseJoinColumns` attribute should have their `referencedColumnName` attribute specified.
2. The values of the joinColumns and inverseJoinColumns attributes should be switched. joinColumns is used to reference the source entity. inverseJoinColumns is used to reference the target entity.
3. The `mappedBy` attribute should be `annotations`, and not `annotation`
4. (unrelated, but probably incorrect) : `cascade=CascadeType.ALL` is probably not what you want on a many-to-many. You don't want to delete all the annotations of a triple when this triple is deleted, since these annotations are referenced by other triples.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but I am still getting the same error. The referencedColumnName is the same for the trhee, would it be a problem?? Anyway, I will check CascadeType, thanks

Comment: The reference column name should be the name of the column in the triple table, not a random name (i.e. it's used to tell Hibernate that the uri_concept_subject column of the triple_has_annotation table references the uri_concept_subject column of the triple table. And I think I found the problem : the joinColumns and inverseJoinColumns attribute values should be switched.

Comment: The reference column is the name of the column in annotation table, which is `annotation_id`, because I want to make a Join between Triple and Annotation. `uri_concept_subject` is the name in the database of the field `conceptUriSubject` on Triple.java Is this correct?? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
@ManyToMany(
        cascade={CascadeType.ALL},
        mappedBy = "annotation",
        fetch=FetchType.LAZY
)   
public List<TripleDBModel> getTriples() {
    return triples;
}
```

The `mappedBy` should be  "annotation**s**"

Edit: Have a look at [this wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToMany), especially the bottom section. This is a quite good reference for association mappings etc.