# Can I use 2 primary key (from same table) as foreign key in other table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys

I am trying to develop a website. Is a kind of University website. I did a table named ACCOUNTS for admins,students and lecturer as well. So for admin I created manualy an account and this admin can manage things an website and he can create account for the lecturer and send them the details. For students i created a registrasion page where they can apply for a course, the admin decide how is accepted or not (i have a column in accounts named active and by default all account are created with inactive account). Now the problem is on GRADES table. the information which I need it is Grade-ID, Module-ID, theGrade and account_id for student to know how received the grade, but I would like to add the lecturer how marked as well, the problem is that it has same name (account_ID) because is in same table with the students. how should I do?

Comment: A table can only have one PK but multiple UNIQUEs. We say a FK references a PK/UNIQUE. Your title phrasing is confused.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple foreign keys in one table to one other table in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453731/multiple-foreign-keys-in-one-table-to-one-other-table-in-mysql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *can* have two columns of the `grades` table that reference the primary key of the `accounts` table.

I think that you want something like:

```
create table grades(
    grade_id int primary key,
    grade int,
    module_id int,
    student_id int,
    lecturer_id int,
    constraint fk_grades_student 
        foreign key (student_id) 
        references accounts(account_id),
    constraint fk_grades_lecturer
        foreign key (lecturer_id) 
        references accounts(account_id)

);
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ec2a8ddb329a29fc7962862fbf6901bd)**

Please note, however, that this does not ensure that the referenced account really is a lecturer or student (it just makes sure that it exists in `accounts`). It would be easier to enforce this referential constraint with a different data structure (for example, if there was separated child tables for each account role).